# Как установить значение инпута в качестве параметра функции?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Проблема в том что когда параметрами являются числа все работает нормально. (например: getRandomNumber(1,20)). Но когда я использую способ представленный ниже и ввожу min = 2 и max = 5 получаю 0,1,2,3. Как заставить это работать как при getRandomNumber(1,20)? Если не сложно напишите пожалуйста полную строку исправленного кода.

```
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type = "button" value = "Get random number" onclick = "getRandomNumber(document.getElementById('min').value,document.getElementById('max').value)">
      <input type = "input" id = "min" placeholder = "min">
      <input type = "input" id = "max" placeholder = "max">
      <script>
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      document.body.appendChild(p);

        function getRandomNumber(min,max) {
          p.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тот момент когда вы прибавляете `min` он воспринимается как строка, потому необходимо преобразовать его в число.

Рабочий вариант:

```
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type = "button" value = "Get random number" onclick = "getRandomNumber(document.getElementById('min').value,document.getElementById('max').value)">
      <input type = "input" id = "min" placeholder = "min">
      <input type = "input" id = "max" placeholder = "max">
      <script>
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      document.body.appendChild(p);

        function getRandomNumber(min,max) {
        var randValue = (max-min + 1);
        var randResult = Math.random() * randValue + parseInt(min);
          p.innerHTML = Math.floor(randResult);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можете использовать `valueAsNumber`, если вы хотите минимум кода:

```html
<html> 
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type = "button" value = "Get random number" onclick = "getRandomNumber(document.getElementById('min').valueAsNumber,document.getElementById('max').valueAsNumber)">
    <input type = "number" id = "min" placeholder = "min">
    <input type = "number" id = "max" placeholder = "max">
    <script>
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    document.body.appendChild(p);

    function getRandomNumber(min,max) {
      p.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Только это работает, если `type` = `range`, `number` или `date`-подобный

Answer (score 1):

Когда, javascript берет значения из полей, то он берется как текст, нужно привести их к нужному типу перед использованием.

```
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type = "button" value = "Get random number" onclick = "getRandomNumber(document.getElementById('min').value,document.getElementById('max').value)">
      <input type = "input" id = "min" placeholder = "min">
      <input type = "input" id = "max" placeholder = "max">
      <script>
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      document.body.appendChild(p);

        function getRandomNumber(min,max) {
          var min = new Number(min),
              max = new Number(max);
          p.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```